# Why are entity framework entities partial classes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I recently began using entity framework, and I noticed that generated entities are partial classes.
What are the uses of that? I googled a bit and people mostly speak of validation, but I can add validation on the generated entity as well.

Comment: Back when EF didn't have code-first model generation it was nice to be able to create another partial class with the same name to have [NotMapped] properties and not have them be blown away by database update changes causing your class to be updated and blow your changes away.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the same reason `partial` classes typically exist at all, code generation.

When code is generated; you don't want your additional methods/properties/whatever blown away, so the designers mark such classes `partial` to allow users to put additional code in a different file.

In Code-First, the code-generation aspect of EF has largely become obsolete so any EF model classes *you* create do not need `partial`.

Answer (score 18):

`partial` is added to generated entities for customization.

In situations when you wish to add your own methods to classes produced by code generators, including EF, it is a good idea to put your implementation in a separate file, so that you wouldn't run the risk of losing your customizations each time the code is re-generated.

Without `partial` developers wishing to customize the class would have to use work-around techniques, such as applying [*Generation Gap*](https://www.martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/generationGap.html) design pattern.

Answer (score -4):

Marking it as partial allows you to put attributes to that class. 
It is handy for example when you need to mark DB generated class as `Serializable` to be able to store it in Session object (when SQL server mode is used in balanced environments).