# Entity Framework - inheriting from model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to the Entity Framework and I've followed tutorials online to create my SQL Server database and made several models and a context class to include properties to access them.

This is my account model:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is my context class:

```
 public class DashContext : DbContext
{
    public DashContext()
    : base(Constants.ConnectionString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DashContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

This works - when I access the DbSet property I can access all the account entires in my database.

However, I want to create an implmentation of the `Account` class that contains more properties than just columns because it has to interact with my program.

So, I tried to do the following:

```
public class GameAccount : Account
{
    public int SomeSpecialProperty { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I'm using my context class to get the `Account` object, I'm not sure how to convert it to `GameAccount`. I **know** I can create a constructor that copies the properties from `Account` to `GameAccount`, like this:

```
public class GameAccount
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public GameAccount(Account model)
    {
        this.ID = model.ID;
        this.Username = model.Username;
        this.Password = model.Password;
    }
}
```

...but that seems a bit inefficent to me and I'm sure there's a simpler way.

What do you think?

Comment: Create another property in the Context like `public DbSet<GameAccount> GameAccounts {get;set;}` and there you'll have all those rows.

Comment: @dcg This is incorrect. The Entity Framework will attempt to query to a table called "GameAccount".

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

**Option 1**

Use a `partial` class as indicated by Fruchtzwerg.

**Option 2**

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map the items from one type to the other. Here is an example:

```
// Notice the ReverseMap call. That will allow mapping in both directions.
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
    cfg.CreateMap<Account, GameAccount>().ReverseMap());
var account = Mapper.Map<Account>(new GameAccount());
var gameAccount = Mapper.Map<GameAccount>(account);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Copy Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx) could be very costly to develop and maintenance. Typically generated classes of the Entity Framework are partial.

[BradleyDotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634184/why-are-entity-framework-entities-partial-classes) explains:

> When code is generated; you don't want your additional methods/properties/whatever blown away, so the designers mark such classes partial to allow users to put additional code in a different file.

So a possible approach is extending the class

```
public partial class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

with additional properties like

```
public partial class Account
{
    public int SomeSpecialProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are almost right. But there is no code generation in this case because it is code first approach.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, but he was just giving the example from the generated code. This is probably my solution - but it seems a bit weird having my classes separate and still specifing same namespace. Can't I use different namespaces?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams No, a partial class have to be written in the same namespace (have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504288/partial-class-in-different-namespaces)