# Define empty constructor in EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am doing Database-First principle in EF6 and I want to define empty constructor for every class but
classes are getting overriden every time i need to make an update on database models.

For example want to implement this constructor to every class but how can configure it in modelBuilder in DbContext?

```
public partial class Address
 {
        public Guid AddressesId { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; } = null!;
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Region { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTimeStamp { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModificationTimeStamp { get; set; }


        public Address()
        {
           AddressesId = Guid.NewGuid();
           IsDeleted = false;
           CreationTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
           ModificationTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

}
```

So that every time i scaffold database i dont lose constructors

** EDIT **
Every class is partial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634184/why-are-entity-framework-entities-partial-classes

Comment: You're asking for a lot of pain if you're going to fight with EF this way.  If the idea is you want to control those for every new instantiation create a parallel domain class you translate the unmolested EF objects through a layer you use to access the DB

Comment: So if i understand correctly, its better to leave out constructors and on every new instantiation to manually handle setting ID(and other properties) to new Guid?

Comment: You can override the `SaveChanges` of your dbcontext and inside check all your newly added entities and if the id is empty, set a new value.